# How know if a npm module is for frontend

Tags: npm, bower

I use in my gulp tasks, a module bower-files. This, return to me all main files from my frontend dependencies, then I use these references, to concat all dependencies, or whatever.

I thinking about use NPM instead Bower to manager my frontend dependencies too, but I don't know any way to see type of npm dependency, if is frontend, or backend.

Any ideas?

Comment: May I ask why it is important for you to categorize them into fontend vs. backend?

Comment: Because I have a lot of things to do with frontend dependecies, for i.e., concat all frontend dependencies, of type javascript, in a vendor.js, and all css in a vendor.css

Comment: Why do you need to concat all those files? Are you able to use Browserify instead?

Comment: I need concat because is served to site, with less requests, increase load page performance. I dont know Browserify, but I will check behavior of their now

Comment: Do check out Browserify. It concats for you. You can require all your front-end dependencies in one file and then browserify it in a gulp task.